# Can the Protection from Evil and Good spell be used on the caster?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

Can the [*protection from evil and good*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/protection-from-evil-and-good) spell be used on the caster?

It doesn't say anything about it in the descripton but I know that some spells prevent them from being used on the spellcaster.

Answer (score 18):

### Spells with range of *Touch* can be cast on self

The Players Handbook states under the heading **[Range](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Range)** (PHB 202, emphasis mine):

> The target of a spell must be within the spell’s range. For a spell like magic missile, the target is a creature. For a spell like fireball, the target is the point in space where the ball of fire erupts.
>
> Most spells have ranges expressed in feet. **Some spells can target only a creature (including you) that you *touch*.**

As indicated here in the description of *Range*, a spell with the range of *Touch* can be cast on yourself.
[*Protection from Evil and Good*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/protection-from-evil-and-good) has a range of *Touch* so the spellcaster can cast it on themselves.

Answer (score 15):

In the Spellcasting section of the PHB, under ["Targeting Yourself"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#TargetingYourself), it says:

> If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can choose yourself, unless the creature must be hostile or specifically a creature other than you. If you are in the area of effect of a spell you cast, you can target yourself.

The spell doesn't specify anything about restrictions on the target so **yes**. You can cast this spell and many other Touch spells on yourself.

Answer (score 6):

According to D&D Beyond,

> Until the spell ends, one willing creature you touch is protected [...]

It doesn't specify "other creature" or "enemy creature", so assuming you're capable of touching yourself, it may target its own caster just fine.

Comment: And that you are willing which you probably are

Comment: I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't let me fix my quote, apparently you edited it less than 10 seconds after I posted it :P

Comment: @DaleM So...  if you were Dominated, and forced to cast _protection_ on yourself, but you liked being Dominated (the spell effect, not anything else), you could cause the spell to fail...  by asserting your free will...  to prevent yourself from asserting your free will...  and overusing ellipses...